# Hive hplsql stored procedure cannot insert timestamp values

Tags: hive, hive-hplsql

I try to use Hive HPL/SQL stored procedure's insert data into hive table. But it is unable to insert timestamp value. My table defined as following:

```
     col_name    |   data_type   | comment  |
+----------------+---------------+----------+
| id             | bigint        |          |
| clean_batchid  | bigint        |          |
| job_name       | varchar(50)   |          |
| table_name     | varchar(30)   |          |
| begin_time     | timestamp     |          |
| end_time       | timestamp     |          |
| clean_type     | varchar(20)   |          |
| total_count    | bigint        |          |
| clean_count    | bigint        |          |
| description    | varchar(500)  |
```

I use the hive cli to insert value without any problem.

```
insert into nbl_clean_batch 
values(12345, 1, 'tryme','B', '2016-12-12 12:52:43', '2016-12-12 12:56:19', 0, 10, 5, 'bbb');
```

but when I use the hplsql to execute the following script:

```
START_DATE := SYSDATE;
END_DATE := SYSDATE;

INSERT INTO TABLE NBL_CLEAN_BATCH
(
    ID, CLEAN_BATCHID, JOB_NAME, TABLE_NAME, BEGIN_TIME, END_TIME,  CLEAN_TYPE, TOTAL_COUNT, CLEAN_COUNT, DESCRIPTION
)
VALUES (
    23456, 1, 'bbb', 'B', START_DATE, END_DATE, 0, 9, 2, 'line'
);
```

it throws the following exception:

> Unhandled exception in HPL/SQL
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 2:27 mismatched input '-' expecting ) near '2016' in value row constructor
>   at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccess(Utils.java:267)
>       at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccessWithInfo(Utils.java:253)
>       at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.runAsyncOnServer(HiveStatement.java:310)
>       at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:250)
>       at org.apache.hive.hplsql.Conn.executeSql(Conn.java:110)
>       at org.apache.hive.hplsql.Exec.executeSql(Exec.java:592)
>       at org.apache.hive.hplsql.Stmt.insertValues(Stmt.java:800)
>       at org.apache.hive.hplsql.Stmt.insert(Stmt.java:713)
>       at org.apache.hive.hplsql.Exec.visitInsert_stmt(Exec.java:1116)
>       at org.apache.hive.hplsql.Exec.visitInsert_stmt(Exec.java:52)
>       at org.apache.hive.hplsql.HplsqlParser$Insert_stmtContext.accept(HplsqlParser.java:10330)
>       at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.AbstractParseTreeVisitor.visitChildren(AbstractParseTreeVisitor.java:70)
>       at org.apache.hive.hplsql.Exec.visitStmt(Exec.java:1009)
>       at org.apache.hive.hplsql.Exec.visitStmt(Exec.java:52)
>       at org.apache.hive.hplsql.HplsqlParser$StmtContext.accept(HplsqlParser.java:1015)
>       at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.AbstractParseTreeVisitor.visitChildren(AbstractParseTreeVisitor.java:70)
>       at org.apache.hive.hplsql.HplsqlBaseVisitor.visitBlock(HplsqlBaseVisitor.java:28)
>       at org.apache.hive.hplsql.HplsqlParser$BlockContext.accept(HplsqlParser.java:449)
>       at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.AbstractParseTreeVisitor.visitChildren(AbstractParseTreeVisitor.java:70)
>       at org.apache.hive.hplsql.Exec.visitProgram(Exec.java:916)
>       at org.apache.hive.hplsql.Exec.visitProgram(Exec.java:52)
>       at org.apache.hive.hplsql.HplsqlParser$ProgramContext.accept(HplsqlParser.java:392)
>       at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.AbstractParseTreeVisitor.visit(AbstractParseTreeVisitor.java:42)
>       at org.apache.hive.hplsql.Exec.run(Exec.java:771)
>       at org.apache.hive.hplsql.Exec.run(Exec.java:747)
>       at org.apache.hive.hplsql.Hplsql.main(Hplsql.java:23)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
>   Caused by: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 2:27 mismatched input '-' expecting ) near '2016' in value row constructor
>       at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.toSQLException(Operation.java:394)
>       at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.prepare(SQLOperation.java:199)
>       at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runInternal(SQLOperation.java:282)
>       at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.run(Operation.java:334)
>       at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementInternal(HiveSessionImpl.java:505)
>       at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementAsync(HiveSessionImpl.java:492)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor43.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:78)
>       at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.access$000(HiveSessionProxy.java:36)
>       at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy$1.run(HiveSessionProxy.java:63)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
>       at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:59)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.executeStatementAsync(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.executeStatementAsync(CLIService.java:297)
>       at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.ExecuteStatement(ThriftCLIService.java:506)
>       at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1437)
>       at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1422)
>       at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
>       at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
>       at org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor.process(TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56)
>       at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:286)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseException:line 2:27 mismatched input '-' expecting ) near '2016' in value row constructor
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:207)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:465)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1301)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileAndRespond(Driver.java:1279)
>       at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.prepare(SQLOperation.java:197)

Any idea why?

Thanks,

Comment: hplsql version is 0.3.31

Answer (score 0):

I have used this format before ...

```
hive> set CURRENT_DATE=FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP());    
hive> select ${hiveconf:CURRENT_DATE}, * from tab1;
OK
2016-12-14 13:43:13     1       100
2016-12-14 13:43:13     2       235325
2016-12-14 13:43:13     3       3242
2016-12-14 13:43:13     4       32543
Time taken: 1.377 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)
hive> set CURRENT_TIMESTAMP = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
hive> select ${hiveconf:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP}, * from tab1;
OK
2016-12-14 13:43:35.425 1       100
2016-12-14 13:43:35.425 2       235325
2016-12-14 13:43:35.425 3       3242
2016-12-14 13:43:35.425 4       32543
Time taken: 1.32 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)
hive>
```

Comment: Hi, CURRENT_DATE function is working. But not timestamp function, such as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, SYSDATE.

Comment: Updated script what I have executed